Arduino環境でGNSS add-onボードを用いてNMEAとQZQSMを同時に出力した場合NMEAが正常に出力されない
開発環境
Windows 11 Home 22H2
Arduino IDE 2.3.2
Spresense v3.2.0 (release 2024/2/9)
Spresense GNSS Add-onボード FW v00.144
やりたいこと
Arduino環境でGNSS add-onボードを用いてGGAセンテンス，GSAセンテンス，QZQSMセンテンスを出力するコードを作成したい．
問題点
サンプルプログラムgnss_addon_qzqsm.inoのNMEA_SetMask2()の引数を0b100000000000101変更した場合，NMEAセンテンスが正常に出力されない．
18:22:08.215 -> $GPGGA,2240000.00,,,,,0,00,,,,,,,*7C
18:22:08.215 -> $GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*2C
18:22:09.164 -> $GPGGA,1712802.341484,,,,,0,00,,,,,,,*79
18:22:09.164 -> $GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*2C
18:22:09.199 -> $QZQSM,61,53ADF2BD118002C3E8588ACB118162352C474588FCB1F6963F200013800120C*0C
18:22:10.176 -> $GPGGA,2240000.00,,,,,0,00,,,,,,,*7C
18:22:10.176 -> $GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*2C
18:22:10.206 -> $QZQSM,61,C6B0840DE000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001C34*0C

試したこと
GNSS add-onボードを用いないgnss_qzqsm.inoで同様の方法でNMEAとQZQSMを同時に出力した場合は正常に出力される．
NMEA_DcReport_Output2()による出力を行わない場合は正常に出力する．（個人情報保護のため緯度経度は#で代用しています．）
void loop()
{
  if (Gnss.waitUpdate(-1)) {
    Gnss.getPositionData(&PositionData);
    NMEA_Output2(&PositionData.Data);

    \\void *handle = Gnss.getDCReport();
    \\if (handle) {
    \\  NMEA_DcReport_Output2((struct cxd56_gnss_dcreport_data_s*)handle);
    \\}
  }
}

18:31:51.157 -> $GPGGA,093151.00,####.####,N,#####.####,E,2,06,1.3,112.5,M,38.7,M,,*6C
18:31:51.157 -> $GNGSA,A,3,11,13,15,29,,,,,,,,,1.8,1.3,1.2,1*34
18:31:51.157 -> $GNGSA,A,3,56,02,,,,,,,,,,,1.8,1.3,1.2,5*3C
18:31:52.197 -> $GPGGA,093152.00,####.####,N,#####.####,E,2,06,1.3,111.9,M,38.7,M,,*6A
18:31:52.197 -> $GNGSA,A,3,11,13,15,29,,,,,,,,,1.8,1.3,1.2,1*34
18:31:52.197 -> $GNGSA,A,3,56,02,,,,,,,,,,,1.8,1.3,1.2,5*3C

蛇足
SpresenseArduinoチュートリアルには以下のような記載があるが実際は複数個所関数を変える必要があり，事実に即していないのではないか？NMEA_InitMask()→NMEA_InitMask2()など．

内蔵GNSSを用いたアプリケーションをGNSS Add-onボードで動作させる場合、スケッチ上の SpGnss クラスを SpGnssAddon クラスへ変更するだけで簡単に移植することができます。


NMEAとQZQSMを同時に出力する場合、GNSSライブラリの中でQZQSMを読み出した後に、
読み出し位置を元に戻す処理が抜けていました。
回避策として、GNSS.cppのgetDCReport()関数において、以下に示すように、
read()後にlseek()処理を追加することで、QZQSMとNMEAの同時出力が可能になります。
是非試してみてください。
void* SpGnss::getDCReport(void)
{
    int ret;
    static struct cxd56_gnss_dcreport_data_s s_dcreport;
    struct cxd56_gnss_dcreport_data_s dcreport;

    ret = lseek(fd_, CXD56_GNSS_READ_OFFSET_DCREPORT, SEEK_SET);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    ret = read(fd_, &dcreport, sizeof(dcreport));

    // ★★★次のlseek()処理を追加する★★★
    lseek(fd_, CXD56_GNSS_READ_OFFSET_LAST_GNSS, SEEK_SET);

    if (ret < 0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }



恒久的な対策はSDK側のコード修正になるため、GitHub の Issue へ登録しておきました。
https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense/issues/743
次回SDKバージョンアップで修正予定です。
